# Control Character Encoding of Fetch Request Body on Mobile Safari

Tags: character-encoding, fetch, mobile-safari

Is there anyway to force mobile safari to encode the string in `UTF-8` without normalizing it?

I'm trying to POST a string containing `U+2126` (Ω) to an HTTP API using fetch. This works fine on desktop Chrome, but when executed on Mobile Safari the server receives `U+3a9` (Ω) instead.

I suspect this is a result of Mobile Safari normalizing before encoding since `U+3a9` is the decomposition of `U+2126`. My read of [section 5.2 of the Fetch spec](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#bodyinit-unions) is a string body should always be encoded to `UTF-8` but there is nothing I can see about normalizing it.

Simplified, the calling code is:

```
const body = '{"value":"73Ω"}';
fetch(
  'https://<endpoint>',
  {
    body,
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  },
);
```

I have checked the codepoint of the string passed to fetch as follows and confirmed that the browser things it's `U+2126` on Mobile Safari.

```
> body.codePointAt(12).toString(16)
2126
```

And have confirmed using an HTTP debugging proxy that the byte sequence sent is different between the two browsers:

- Desktop Chrome: `e284a6` - the `UTF-8` encoding of `U+2126`
- Mobile Safari: `cea9` - the `UTF-8` encoding of `U+3a9`

I have tried explicitly setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json;charset=UTF-8` but that does not have any effect on how the string is sent.

When I explicitly encode the string to `UTF-8` using [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) and pass an `ArrayBuffer` to fetch, the correct `U+2126` character appears to be sent as expected. i.e. the following code appears to work around the issue:

```
const body = '{"value":"73Ω"}';
fetch(
  'https://<endpoint>',
  {
    body: new TextEncoder().encode(body),
    method: 'post',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  },
);
```

But this seems bizarre as it's the same conversion fetch is supposed to be performing.

[Webkit bugzilla 213254](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213254) suggests that text encoder used to normalize, but that was fixed. I suspect this behavior is still present in the fetch implementation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, even just confirmation that this is a known issue.